# При отладке возникает ошибка в последней строке "Невозможно преобразовать Array в Object[][]. (строка 24, файл)"

Tags: json, google-spreadsheet

```
function pullJSON() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheets = ss.getSheets();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


      var url="https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/ticker"; // Paste your JSON URL here

       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
      var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
      var dataSet = dataAll;


      var rows = [],
          data;


      for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
        data = dataSet[i];
        rows.push("cur", "last", "high"); //your JSON entities here
      }

      dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 3); // 3 Denotes total number of entites
      dataRange.setValues(rows);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужен массив массивов:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  data = dataSet[i];
  rows.push(["cur", "last", "high"]); //your JSON entities here
}
```